Can I use supabase auth for my personally hosted backend?
Can a successful login on the frontend, using supabase auth, be passed along to my backend? I don't mean the special backend services from supabase. I mean, just my own nodejs application on an EC2 instance.
I've tried passing the access_token from my front end supabase session in calls to my nodejs endpoints and then using jwt verifiers. No dice. I've also tried using the service_role secret from the supabase dashboard.
I've also tried using jwksClient as an extra step in the backend. Nothing works.
Invalid signature, etc. etc.
So many hours spent.

Yes, you should be able to take the JWT secret from your Supabase dashboard and verify the access token using it.
